# how to add vertical lines in shape layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shapes

I got this:
[image]

And what I want is:
[image]

Don't mind the color right now.
I figured out how to do the horizontal lines, but not the vertical lines.
So how to add vertical lines?

This is my row_border.xml (shape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#99cc00" />

</shape>
```

Tried this already, but that didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#99cc00" />

    <stroke
        android:angle="90"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"
        ></stroke>

</shape>
```

Comment: what layout are you using? Custom listview or table view?

Comment: @LazyNinja Table view, sorry didn't knew it was important to notice it on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use tablelayout,

1- give TableLayout background  android:background="#000000"

2- give your TableRow different background (it will be border color)

3  give your TableRow margin (it will be border width)

left  margin  = left border

right  margin  = right  border

top  margin  = top border

bottom  margin  = bottom border

[image]

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt5"
                android:text="Hello World 6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did `setBackgroundResource` on every `textView`, then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use TableLayout for your situation

Comment: Seems he is using tablelayout. I have asked it on the comments section

Comment: I make the table programmatically (not in a xml file).